# Is live streaming music while learning/practicing a good idea?

Tags: classical-guitar, flute

I am learning Western Classical Guitar and Indian Bamboo Flute. I want to stream myself playing, connect with the community, and get some good feedback as well. Is it really a bad idea to live stream myself learning/practicing music. FYI my channel is [knightrolls]. [1](https://www.twitch.tv/knightrolls). Perhaps some experts or enthusiasts here could provide some good advice.

Comment: This question doesn't really have a concrete, objective answer, and [Stack Exchange isn't suited to open-ended discussion](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Feel free to bring it up in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room), though. There could be both pros and cons to the idea.

Comment: @ananta Sorry but your question couldn't be accepted, as practice questions normally use the following levels: 1. specific practice issue (acceptable); 2. knowing about possible practice problems, highlighting specific points about which you're uncertain (acceptable if about common practice, possibly for a specific genre, and if not asking about *too many* unrelated issues) 3. asking for responses about generic playing (not acceptable, as too broad); 4. asking for *ways* to get responses about generic playing (completely off topic). Please take your time to follow the [tour] and read [ask].